# Images not showing in LazyVGrid but working in LazyHStack/Grid

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI with just a few months under my belt but I have been able to work through many problems by myself but this one has me completely stumped. Please take no notice of the layout or code I'm just concentrating on getting it to work right now.

I am using Apple's Landmark code to teach myself how everything works with different views etc but I now have hit a wall trying to get images to show on a particular view but only when using LazyVGrid.

I am returning a filtered list of locations based on a category tag having been clicked. I want to have two items across (with an image of the location and then its name below) and then continue on down the page as it loops through the array of filtered locations. Everything works 100% if I use a LazyHStack or a Grid/GridRow but as soon as I put in a LazyVGrid to get the layout I want, the page goes blank.

```
// Filtered List Of Locations
let columns = [GridItem(.flexible(), alignment: .top), GridItem(.flexible(), alignment: .top)]
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 10) {
                        ForEach(categoryFilter) { landmark in
                            NavigationLink {
                                DetailView(landmark: landmark)
                            } label: {
                                CategoryItem(landmark: landmark)
                            }
                            .frame(height: 185)
                        }
                    }
```

Moving ForEach above LazyVGrid "works" but of course doesn't achieve a grid.

If I comment out the image section of CategoryItem (below) then it all works and displays the landmark.nameEnglish text but if I uncomment the images section I get the blank view again. I just can't see any reason for it.

I tested with Nuke and Async and the same thing happens but if I make the images local it all works properly.

```
// CategoryItem View
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            if let images = landmark.images {
            ForEach(images.prefix(1), id: \.self) { imageURLString in
                    KFImage(URL(string: imageURLString))
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
                }
            }
            Text(landmark.nameEnglish!)
                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                .font(.title2)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
        }
```

Thanks for any help you can offer in solving this.

Comment: Have you tried adding a specific height to the `LazyVGrid`, eg. `.frame(height: 333)`

Comment: Thanks yes I have tried that but it makes no difference. There is seemingly an endless loop generated by using LazyVGrid which I noticed after running a print statement to the console in Xcode. I remove LazyVGrid and run the bare ForEach loop and it all works I just can't see why.